# Covert Node.js Crypto HMAC to Go-lang HMAC Encryption

Tags: node.js, go, encryption

I have the following node.js code when doing a password hash.

> body.password = covid@19

```
salt = "hello@world"
body.passwordhex = crypto.createHmac('sha256', salt).update(body.password).digest('hex');
```

It's giving the following result:

> 5fbbff7f6b4db4df6308c6ad7e8fd5afcea513bb70ca12073c7bec618c6b4959

---

Now, I am trying to convert this to it's go-lang equivalent and my code is

> body_password := "covid@19"

```
salt := "hello@world"

// Create a new HMAC by defining the hash type and the key (as byte array)
h := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte(key))

// Write Data to it
h.Write([]byte(salt))

// Get result and encode as hexadecimal string
hash := hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
```

And the go-lang result is

> 9b0cb661fcea1bbfe1fa38912e8610f8c0e4707739021988006368c1ba8da8b7

What could be wrong on my go-lang code? Was it the digest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javascript code uses `salt` as the HMAC key and hashes the `body_password`.   Do the same thing in Go to get the same result:

```
body_password := "covid@19"
salt := "hello@world"
h := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte(salt))
h.Write([]byte(body_password))
hash := hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
```

Run the program on the GoLang PlayGround: https://play.golang.org/p/GASMDhEhqGi

Comment: Thanks, so I missed reversing the hmac value from the salt vs password.